# Exponential decay of temperature of tea

Tags: exponential-function

A cup of tea is poured at 98 degrees. After two minutes it has reached 94 degrees. The difference between the temperature of the tea and the room temperature (22 degrees) falls exponentially. Find the time it takes for the tea to cool to 78 degrees.

Temperature= $22 + 76\cdot g^t$.

I have got the above equation but I do not know how to find the growth factor. Is the growth factor the constant $e$? If so, can you explain why?

thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to find the growth factor from your data.  Plug in the fact that after two minutes the temperature is $94$ degrees
$$94=22+76g^2$$
Solve for $g$.